# My computer stops working after I choose install ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04

I can boot Ubuntu easily and choose options but when I select install inside windows 8 and press continue , a black screen appears and Ubuntu CD comes out and if I press a button, the computer restarts.
I have windows 8 acer laptop.

Answer (score 1):

haha,
Sorry to laugh first off (more of a giggle really) but I just finished a 4 WEEK stretch with the same issue. I know you pain (if you have formatted at LEAST 10 times with various options).

1. Disable secure boot. Install.
2. Enable secure boot. Install.
   There should be an option menu after pressing a key during boot up that gives various devices to boot from
   (Selecting the option with EFI: / UEFI: disables secure boot)

Fix for me: Download and run boot repair.
This is also included in ubuntu-secure-remix (non-official ubuntu)

I wish you the best of luck.